Is there a way to cancel request manually in transformRequest?
Is there a way to cancel the request in transformRequest?
I'd like to avoid some of the requests for certain zoom levels (I can parse zoom level from URL) so I can implement overzooming but without introducing separate layers for different zoom level ranges.
Is this possible?
